# java.lang.IllegalStateException when I using Room library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I use several data classes with @Entity and relevant interfaces with @Dao. So, I'm using the code below to get work with my database

Code example I found on https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#kotlin

```kotlin
val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
    applicationContext,
    LocalDatabase::class.java,
    name = "local_copy_ver3"
).build()
lessons.value = GetStudentsLessons(db, gradebook.value)
```

But on runtime, i see in logcat this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading a state that was created after the snapshot was taken or in a snapshot that has not yet been applied
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.readError(Snapshot.kt:1865)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.current(Snapshot.kt:2171)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutableStateImpl.setValue(SnapshotState.kt:299)
    at mypackagename.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:79)
    at mypackagename.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:78)
    at mypackagename.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke$lambda$5(MainActivity.kt:78)
    at mypackagename.MainActivity$onCreate$1.$r8$lambda$KWKwuVyUZMqgAAr1XDcXUMNuzmM(Unknown Source:0)
    at mypackagename.MainActivity$onCreate$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:933)
```

I've tried to add `delay(350)`, and this exception disappeared:

```kotlin
Thread { runBlocking { launch {
    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
        applicationContext,
        LocalDatabase::class.java,
        name = "local_copy_ver3"
    ).build()
    delay(350)
    lessons.value = GetStudentsLessons(database.value!!, gradebook.value)
} } }.start()
```

This works on my device, but may crash on more slowly devices (for example, emulator on my laptop).

Is there a more correct solution to the problem so as not to create a large delay and not lose the stability of the application?

There are one of my entities:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class LessonViewItem(
    @PrimaryKey val lesson_id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name="date") var date: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name="time_index") var time_index: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name="auditory_name") var auditory_name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="lesson_type_name") var lesson_type_name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="teacher_name") var teacher_name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="discipline_name") var discipline_name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="group_name") var group_name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="subgroup") var subgroup: Int? = null
)
```

And Dao for this entity:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface LessonViewDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM LessonViewItem")
    fun GetAll() : List<LessonViewItem>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM LessonViewItem WHERE lesson_id=:lesson_id")
    fun GetOne(lesson_id: Int) : LessonViewItem?

    @Update
    fun Update(item: LessonViewItem)

    @Insert
    fun Insert(vararg items: LessonViewItem)

    @Query("DELETE FROM LessonViewItem")
    fun Clear()
}
```

And Database abstract class:

```kotlin
@Database(
    entities = [
        InstituteItem::class,
        CafedraItem::class,
        GroupItem::class,
        TeacherItem::class,
        DisciplineItem::class,
        LessonTypeItem::class,
        AuditoryItem::class,
        StudentItem::class,
        LessonItem::class,
        LessonViewItem::class,
        Parameter::class
    ],
    version = 2)
@TypeConverters(IntListConverter::class, DateConverter::class)
abstract class LocalDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun InstituteDao(): InstituteDao
    abstract fun CafedraDao(): CafedraDao
    abstract fun GroupDao(): GroupDao
    abstract fun TeacherDao(): TeacherDao
    abstract fun DisciplineDao(): DisciplineDao
    abstract fun LessonTypeDao(): LessonTypeDao
    abstract fun AuditoryDao(): AuditoryDao
    abstract fun StudentDao(): StudentDao
    abstract fun LessonDao(): LessonDao
    abstract fun LessonViewDao(): LessonViewDao
    abstract fun ParameterDao(): ParameterDao
}
```